# Blank Home Page on Amazon EC2

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing.

My CodeIngiter application is working fine in WAMP using this URL: `http://localhost/myapp`.

However, when I moved it to my AWS EC2 micro instance Amazon Linux AMI `/var/www/html/myapp` and tried to access my application using this URL, `http://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp`, all I get is a blank white page.

Here is everything I tried:

**1. Disabled "Index of" display**

> cd /etc/httpd/conf/
>   sudo nano httpd.conf
>   Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

**2. Turned on Error reporting in php.ini**

> error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
>   display_errors = On

**3. Development Environment**
In the `index.php` (root of my applicaiton),

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

**4. Restarted Apache**
cd /etc/init.d
sudo httpd -k restart

**5. DocumentRoot**

`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"`
Also tried: 
`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`
`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myapp"`

**6. echo test from index.php**

I printed a test message from both my `index.php`
(root of my app), as well as my controller. Both
worked. I don't understand why my view is not being
displayed.

`<?php echo "test"; ...
 //This worked.`

**7. Replaced** `www/html/myapp` **with** `www/html/`

I moved the contents of my application outside of "myapp"
folder into `www/html` directory. 
Also, `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"`. 
Also, my **.htaccess** file (in root of myapp)
is `"RewriteBase /"` (see point 8 below).
Also, I removed **.htaccess** from `/var/www/html/`
but same blank page.

**8. .htaccess**

The following `.htaccess` file is located in the root
of my CodeIgniter application. I also tried changing
`RewriteBase /myapp` to `RewriteBase /` but I'm still 
getting this blank page with no errors.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /myapp

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I do not know what to try again.

Comment: If you were able to echo from your controller, then CI is working. Can you do the same with the view (just use some test text)? Also would be helpful to see the controller and view code.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply @stormdrain. I've edited my question to include the code for the controller, and two views. search_page2.php is the view that is supposed to load first.

Comment: So, as a sanity check (as a friend might say), if you replace all that code in the controller, in `index()` with just `$this->load->view('search_page2');`, does it work?

Comment: +1 wow no it does not work when I put $this->load->view('search_page2');

Comment: Can you please delete this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16722514/183254 ? Bad practice to repost... Plus we've determined none of the things in there are the issue. Thx.

Comment: I'm thinking, it works in WAMP. So it has to be something with the way I configured EC2, no?

Comment: If it works in WAMP, then there seems to be something different on EC2 that is preventing me from accessing that controller.

Comment: I thought you said you could echo form the controller? We need to isolate the issue. **1)** In the controller, in the index() method can you `echo "test";` ? If so, **2)** in the controller, in index() call `$this->load->view('search_page2');` AND in search_page2.php only put "test" (delete everything else). Does that work?

Comment: +1 Yes I thought so too. But on double checking, I realized that I can only echo from the index.php in the root, not the controller. Sorry about that!

Comment: OK, I just joined AWS, created a micro, installed httpd and php, opened port 80 (in AWS console, I don't think iptables is on by default), SCP'd codeigniter, and it works fine (I can see the CI welcome page). It's possible something got corrupt or missed when you uploaded your stuff. Try creating a new instance (hey, they're free!) and seeing if you can get a default CI install working.

Comment: **1)** I can't `echo "Test";`from the controller. **2)** I can't call $this->load->view('search_page2'); AND echo "test" in the search_page2.php after deleting everything else (but I can do this in WAMP!). No it does not work on EC2.

Comment: Really! I did all of my development in WAMP first. Then when it was finished, I uploaded it to EC2. I did not upload codeigniter to EC2 first.

Comment: It sounds like I'm going to have to do it your way and upload a fresh copy of CI first.

Comment: I got no errors when I uploaded to EC2 using FileZilla. However, this is very encouraging. I will upload it first, then develop it there (although working in nano using Putty is a bit slow and a little more difficult than working with Notepad++ on my computer)

Comment: So thats it @stormdrain. I should start over on EC2 first? Or just reupload my application again?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would fire up a new micro and get a stock CI install working. Once working, I'd port over the code. Clean slate and all that. Shouldn't take that long; just copy and paste the code :) BUT it might not hurt to try to delete everything and re-upload the code. check out http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Comment: Stock CI from Elis Lab? Or from the Community EMIs on Amazon?

Comment: I used ellis lab. It looks like the community EMI isn't free...either way, same thing (except for the free part)

Comment: Oh ok cool. Thank you so much! This is the first time I'm uploading any application to any host, far less any cloud provider. So I'll do it over the right way this time. And thanks for recommending SCP. I'll go get some sleep now and start again in a few hours. Thanks very much! I can't stress this enough.

Comment: No problem. You'll get the hang of it :)

Comment: hey @stormdrain I just want to let you know that I followed your advice and its now working! After creating a new instance and getting a fresh copy of CodeIgniter, I did the following and it worked: 
`usermod -a -G apache ec2-user`   
`chmod 777 /var/www/html -R`      Thanks again!